# What is the advantage of asynchronous approach in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Maybe it is a stupid question, and it is apparent for everyone, but what is the advantage of an asynchronous Ajax call in JavaScript if the language itself is single-threaded?

Comment: Why negative votes? This is a valid and good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous requests allow you to keep the website / app `alive` while the stuff, which is unimportant for the user, is handled in the background without interrupting the user's experience.

Some advantages are

1. Improved user experience
2. Non-blocking browser behaviour (imagine your browser being stuttering otherwise)
3. Handle multiple requests in the background

Answer (score 0):

The advantage is that synchronous waits for a response to return/complete; while asynchronous does it while there's already a request ongoing. Synchronous 'waits' for a response before proceeding; asynchronous doesn't.

Comment: You've actually only defined the difference but not given any reasons why one is beneficial over the other.